# GAE Python: Search by Date using dateutil.parser

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, search, python-dateutil

I'm implementing a free text search feature. User can enter any keyword, e.g. a date string..

I want it to be flexible: "2013 Oct", "Oct 2013", "2013-10" etc. should all be recognised. And because App Engine search API only recognise date formate as YYYY-MM-DD, if I get "2013 Oct", I need to translate it into "search_date >= 2013-10-01 and search_date <= 2013-10-31".

I manage to use dateutil.parser.parse(search_date_str), but the problem is if any date component is missing, it will use today's data. e.g. "2013 Oct" will be parsed as "2013-10-27". In that case, I can't tell if user is keying "2013 Oct 27" or just "2013 Oct". Same for searching by year... if user just want to search "2013" I should be able to translate it into [2013-01-01, 2013-12-31] not "2013-10-27"

I'm not sure how should I do that? I'm thinking if any RegEx is needed (I'm really poor at that...)

Comment: So I looked into the code of dateutil.parser.parse function. It actually set today as default date, and if it detect year, month, day, hour, minute, second data, just use default.replace() to update the search_date... so I modify it a little bit, if day component is to be replaced, I set parse_level be "day" and if not then check for "month" "year".. it's not nice..but at least works for me..

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the built-in *datetime* module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html), particularly the `datetime.strptime` function: (http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). This allow you to create a `datetime` object from a string, with a variety of different formats. For example, you could do this:

```
theString = "2013-10"
theDate = datetime.strptime(theString, "%Y-%m")
theString2 = "2013 Oct"
theDate2 = datetime.strptime(theString, "%Y %b")
```

and various other combinations. If would be much easier if you restricted the allowed input formats, but anyway this should make your life easier. You don't need to write any regular expressions, as the `datetime` module handles this already.

Comment: Your solution only works if I detect the format already. And my bottleneck is how to detect the format at first place. If I know the format user keys in, then I would now how to handle it..

Comment: Which is why I suggest that you restrict the allowed input format. If you can't do that, then you can use *strptime* with various format strings, to check the input against a variety of formats. It will raise an exception if the data does not match the format string.

Comment: I left a comment in my question.. I modified the parse function a little bit, make it return not just parsed datetime but an additional parse_level. Inside the function, I can tell to which level the string is parsed.. Thanks for you answer. I think provide flexibility for users is important :)